# How can i COPY data from one table to other one located in a different Redshift instance?

Tags: csv, testing, amazon-redshift, import-from-csv

I need to copy some Redshift production data into the dev environment. Is there a  fast way to export/import rows in Redshift? Or at least a fast way to import csv structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) and [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) commands to [dump tables to S3 and load](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reloading_unload_files.html) them into a different instance.

Here's [a utility](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/UnloadCopyUtility/redshift-unload-copy.py) that illustrates the process.